# Protobuf encode returns null values

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf.js

I am trying to encode a message to a Buffer using the encode method in protobufjs.

this is my code.

```
setValue(value) {
        var address = makeAddress(value);
        let data = protobuf["Icao"].create({data:value})
        let container = protobuf["IcaoContainer"].create()
        container.entries = data
        console.log(container)
        var stateEntriesSend = {}
        stateEntriesSend[address] = protobuf['IcaoContainer'].encode(container).finish();
        console.log(stateEntriesSend[address])
        return  this.context.setState(stateEntriesSend, this.timeout).then(function(result) {
            console.log("Success", result)
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error", error)
          })
      }
```

the value of  `console.log(container)` is below, which is correct.

```
IcaoContainer {
  entries: 
   Icao {
     data: <Buffer a2 66 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 63 73 65 74 64 64 61 74 61 68 61 73 61 70 6f 69 75 79> } }
```

but I am trying to encode it as a buffer using `protobuf['IcaoContainer'].encode(container).finish()`

and it seems to return an empty buffer. value of `console.log(stateEntriesSend[address])` is below

```
<Buffer >
```

my proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Icao {
  string data = 1;
}

message IcaoContainer {
  repeated Icao entries = 1;
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone else is getting the same problem I have figured out where this went wrong.

according to my Icao message, I have defined in my proto the data should be a string. But when I call the setValue method I am passing a JSON object instead of that string value. so when I use

```
protobuf["Icao"].create({data:value})
```

the value is not a string. that was the problem. according to [protobufjs documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs), it is always a good practice to Verify the payload before you use create method it. like this.

```
 // Exemplary payload
    var payload = { awesomeField: "AwesomeString" };

    // Verify the payload if necessary (i.e. when possibly incomplete or invalid)
    var errMsg = AwesomeMessage.verify(payload);
    if (errMsg)
        throw Error(errMsg);

    // Create a new message
    var message = AwesomeMessage.create(payload); // or use .fromObject if conversion is necessary

    // Encode a message to an Uint8Array (browser) or Buffer (node)
    var buffer = AwesomeMessage.encode(message).finish();
    // ... do something with buffer
```

this threw me an error saying data must be String. that was the issue.

And also since I have used `repeated` keyword in my IcaoContainer `container.entries` should be an array.